# Java Date issues

Tags: java, formatting, date

Im having a problem with java date's, when i pass a date before 1949 into the bellow method.
The date i have returned is for example 2049, im aware it has somthing to do with the date format and thought using yyyy instead of RRRR would have fixed it. But i just  dont understand why or how to reslove it. Any help will be much apreciated

```
public static java.sql.Date parseDate(String date) throws ParseException {
  if (date != null) {
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
   return new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(date).getTime());
  }
  return null;
 }
```

Thanks Jon

Comment: How does the `String date` look like? Comments: 1) You should use `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`. 2) You should use Joda Time instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: "Im having a problem with java date" - That's ok, everybody has

Answer (score 2):

let me format that for you..

```
public static java.sql.Date parseDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    if (date != null) { 
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); 
        return new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(date).getTime()); 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

This I suspect is what you want...

```
private Date convertDate() throws ParseException
{
    String dateStr = "21-02-2010";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    if (dateStr != null)
    {
      date = new Date(dateFormat.parse(dateStr).getTime());
    }

    System.out.println(date);
    return date;
}
```

For 21-02-2010 you will get...
Sun Feb 21 00:00:00 GMT 2010

For 21-02-1938 you will get...
Mon Feb 21 00:00:00 GMT 1938

Does that help? I might of been due to you having MMM in your code.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.sql.Date.valueOf( 
    LocalDate.parse( "12-Jan-23" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ) 
)
```

## Time Zone

Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zone. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

Your code uses `Date` which is always in UTC. So your date value produced from the misnamed `Date` class will be accurate for UTC but not valid for other time zones such as `America/Montreal` or `Asia/Kolkata`.

## Using java.time

The modern way to do this work is with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To parse an incoming string, define a formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter`. Specify a `Locale` for the human language to be used in translating the name of the month.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "12-Jan-2017" , f );
```

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can pass the `LocalDate` directly to your database with `setObject` and `getObject` methods.

For a JDBC driver not yet updated, fall back to the java.sql types.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).